# Chrony allow only 2 IP clients

Tags: linux, chrony

OS: Debian 10.4

Chrony: 3.1

I search how declare 2 IP ADD on /etc/etc/chrony.conf in "allow" option:

- ';'
- ','

with:

- "
- '

Example:

```
allow "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2"
```

But this say:

```
Fatal error: Could not parse allow directive...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found:

I need to put only "," separator.

Example:

```
allow 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2
```

Thank's